# Reward when a friend accepts app invite

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my facebook game I'm trying to create a system where a user can invite their friend to the game, I want it so that if they accept the invite then they both get rewarded I have read the API docs but not quite sure how to link who invited who.

Any help appreciated

Thanks,

Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You know the request id from the callback.  You know who sent the request by the id of the current person logged in.  You know the ids of who was sent an invite.  Store that information in your datastore.

At the time you delete the invites when the user comes back, you know the request id and the new user's id.

But I remember reading somewhere that the user sending the invite cannot get a bonus for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Rewarding a user for liking or responding to an invite is considered against the TOS. They changed the TOS over a year ago to prevent this because the invite system was getting spammed.

I will recommend you to simply change your strategy and instead invite people to accomplish an action related to another player and in that way, they may get a reward for doing so. But giving out rewards to inviting playing is against the TOS.

Now, the how to do this becomes rather simple:

1. Create a table of players
2. Create a table of invites and actions
3. Insert into the the table of invites the player id you want the action to refer to, the action that you intent to do and any other information you need.
4. Via an invite message, send an URL that refers to that invite table record and process the request normally.

Remember that an invite is a url to visit, whatever you pass on to the url, you get it in your app. So it could be a huge url with lots of params that describe what to do or a simple ID that refers to your database and from there you process the request.

Good luck